# Can a given continuous and bounded function be bounded by an integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and bounded function, for any set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$. Is there an integrable function $g$ such that $\left|f\right| \leq g$?

I am not so sure because I cannot find any examples or counterexamples for this. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hint: show that 1) it is true for all your $f$'s iff it is true for $f=1$ (the constant function) and 2) it is true for $f=1$ iff $1$ is integrable (on $\Omega$).

Comment: If $f$ is fixed and bounded on any $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ then it is bounded on $\mathbb{R}.$ Hence $|f|\le g$ for an  integrable function $g$ iff $f$ is absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The OP is not clear but I think he meant "where $\Omega$ is a (fixed) arbitrary set" (instead of "for *any*").